# Windows: What happens if I finish drive letters? (they are 26!)

Tags: windows, drive

What happens if I finish the drive letters?
It's just curiosity, but I have a lot of letters and it happens that I float around 20 when I have everything connected

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This image is not mspaint. I subst'ed all drives, even `B:`

Then, I plugged a card reader that has 4 drives. Nothing showed up!
So, the answer to your question is NOTHING! You are just unable to add more. 
Of cource you can use [volume mounting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938934.aspx) as suggested above

[image]

Comment: Ahahaha nice! well, big fail for microsoft however!

Comment: If you set your local to Greak, then do you loose 2 drives?

Comment: How do you remember what is on what letter?

Comment: @richard for that people use drive labels. Like `Local Disk(G:)` can be labelled as `Videos(G:)` where `Videos` is the disk label and `G:` is drive letter assigned.

Comment: @RBT Can I use drive labels in scripts and programs?

Comment: Microsoft, I love you, you are so smart... drive letters are not a good solution, but as this is what we have for Windows, I should continue as AA: AB: AC: AD: ...

Answer (score 41):

It depends on your operating system. Some older versions of windows supported up to 32 drives (mapped to things like `[:` and `` `: ``), but more recent versions do not.

On a modern Windows machine, if you require more than 26 drives, the correct solution is to use [Volume Mount Points](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938934.aspx)

Comment: I think your answer is the most clever, thanks a lot, you also provided a solution which it wasn't required but really appreciated (I learnt something good too I think)

Comment: I was able to do a driveless mount by using a symbolic link!

"net use \\192.168.1.293\my_share\folder1"
"mklink /d c:\mounts\folder1 \\192.168.1.293\my_share\folder1"

Comment: @Milean ...except that symlinks ain't no substitute for mounts ;(

Comment: @minmaxavg True, but it still works as a path to access files on Windows ;)