# How to determine if a file path is absolute?

Tags: php, linux, windows, path

How can I determine if a file path is absolute? Must work on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Check if it has a colon `:`? Paths the begin with `http://`, `https://`, `file:///`, `C:/` are all absolute. You can also see if the path begins with `/` or `~`.

Comment: @LoganMurphy Unix doesn't

Comment: you read this, maybe is useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392274/checking-for-relative-vs-absolute-paths-urls-in-php

Comment: @xd6_ Unix doesn't what?

Comment: @LoganMurphy sorry, Unix/linux don't use colon in paths the question requires linux  compatability also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here my try at doing it with a single function:

```
function isAbsolutePath($path) {
    if (!is_string($path)) {
        $mess = sprintf('String expected but was given %s', gettype($path));
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException($mess);
    }
    if (!ctype_print($path)) {
       $mess = 'Path can NOT have non-printable characters or be empty';
       throw new \DomainException($mess);
    }
    // Optional wrapper(s).
    $regExp = '%^(?<wrappers>(?:[[:print:]]{2,}://)*)';
    // Optional root prefix.
    $regExp .= '(?<root>(?:[[:alpha:]]:/|/)?)';
    // Actual path.
    $regExp .= '(?<path>(?:[[:print:]]*))$%';
    $parts = [];
    if (!preg_match($regExp, $path, $parts)) {
        $mess = sprintf('Path is NOT valid, was given %s', $path);
        throw new \DomainException($mess);
    }
    if ('' !== $parts['root']) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I took this from one of my project you might find useful while working with files and paths:
[dragonrun1/file_path_normalizer](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8912-PHP-Get-the-full-path-of-files-relative-to-root.html#view_files/files/57428)

Comment: Can't see any problems with that. Will accept. Thanks!

Comment: This is a solution to copypaste from a StackOverflow answer. What I would be more interested in is whether there is currently a "winning" or "de facto standard" solution that has established existence outside StackOverflow, like a library that can be installed with composer or something. Is there a "de facto standard" path utilities library?

Comment: If you look at my answer above I give link to the project I did which is also available through composer.

Comment: I had trouble with this on Windows - I had to change the root capture group to look allow for backslashes instead of only forward slashes. Old: `$regExp .= '(?<root>(?:[[:alpha:]]:/|/)?)';` New:`(?<root>(?:[[:alpha:]]:[/\\\\]|/)`. Note the use of _4_ backslashes, the first and third are doing PHP level escaping, the second is doing regex level escaping.

Comment: If you look at the latest version from my library you'll find I've changed that method a lot and just replace all back-slashes with forward-slashes to start with in the path since windows also allows them.

Comment: @HPierce, i have copied the entire function and added you fix, but I got a regex error, namely: "missing closing parenthesis at offset". So I have added a little at the end and got it working. Old regex: `(?<root>(?:[[:alpha:]]:[/\\\\]|/)` new: `(?<root>(?:[[:alpha:]]:[/\\\\]|/)?)`. See the `?)` at the end.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I've come up with:

```
function is_absolute_path($path) {
    if($path === null || $path === '') throw new Exception("Empty path");
    return $path[0] === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR || preg_match('~\A[A-Z]:(?![^/\\\\])~i',$path) > 0;
}
```

I think that covers all the [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4652545/65387) root paths for Windows.

Comment: It still breaks for paths that have [wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php). try 'zlib://c:/dummy/path/' or 'file://c:/dummy/path'

Comment: @Dragonaire [Node](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_isabsolute_path) returns `false` for both those examples too, which I think is the correct answer. We're talking about *file* paths here, not URLs.

Comment: Guess you need to read the wrapper link I give as they have nothing to do with URLs in and of themselves. You can use them to implement things like ftp around a stream but then you have file:// which does no more then make a local file in a stream resource instead of just a string. The fact that Node(JS) doesn't understand something that is PHP specific doesn't surprise me either ;)

Comment: @Dragonaire Yes, but that's not the point. It depends on your use case. If I'm accepting file paths from a user, for example, do I want to allow them specify wrapper methods? Probably not.

Comment: That's one reason I add the option to not allow them in my little library ;)